# How do you remove a range of rows in a python ndarray matrix?

Tags: python

Suppose I have a 100x100 matrix in Python like below:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.linspace(0,100*100-1,100*100).reshape([100,100,])


print(A)
```

You can see A below:

```
[[0.000e+00 1.000e+00 2.000e+00 ... 9.700e+01 9.800e+01 9.900e+01]
 [1.000e+02 1.010e+02 1.020e+02 ... 1.970e+02 1.980e+02 1.990e+02]
 [2.000e+02 2.010e+02 2.020e+02 ... 2.970e+02 2.980e+02 2.990e+02]
 ...
 [9.700e+03 9.701e+03 9.702e+03 ... 9.797e+03 9.798e+03 9.799e+03]
 [9.800e+03 9.801e+03 9.802e+03 ... 9.897e+03 9.898e+03 9.899e+03]
 [9.900e+03 9.901e+03 9.902e+03 ... 9.997e+03 9.998e+03 9.999e+03]]
```

How do I delete a range of rows (like rows 5 - 50) in A?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a mask array of the elements you want to keep and then just index the array.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.linspace(0,100*100-1,100*100).reshape([100,100,])
mask = np.ones(len(A), dtype=bool)
mask[5:50] = False
A = A[mask]
```

Shape before:

```
(100, 100)
```

Shape after:

```
(55, 100)
```

Answer (score 1):

@RoseGod's answer is probably more pythonic but I thought I'd post this anyway:

```
A = np.asarray([*A[:5], *A[50:]])
```

Comment: @RoseGod's answer is probably more pythonic, but above all more efficient. I measured a factor of 2 between the two methods.

Comment: Definitely! Good point